# Does a binormal category always admit an additive structure?

Tags: ct.category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $\mathsf{C}$ be a category. We call $\mathsf{C}$ binormal if it has a null object, has all equilizers and coequilizers, all monomorphisms are kernels and all epimorphisms are cokernels (whereby a kernel means an equalizer of a morphism and a zero morphism, and cokernel dually). Then my question is:

> Can we make any binormal category a preadditive category?

Here I'm using [wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preadditive_category) of preadditive category.

I know that a binormal category which has all binary products must be abelian. I'm just wondering if we can drop out the requirement of the existence of products.

Comment: I also posted this question at MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828246/does-a-binormal-category-always-admit-an-additive-structure

Comment: Naive attempt at a counterexample: is the category of cyclic groups binormal?

Comment: @MikeShulman Yes. and it is also preadditive.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were asking whether it has biproducts.  Maybe you should include your definition of "pre-additive", since terminology varies.

Comment: @MikeShulman Done, thanks for pointing out that.

Comment: Why not use the completely unambiguous term "$\text{Ab}$-enriched"?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I didn't think there would be ambiguity. Is term "preadditive" really very ambiguous?

Comment: Well, it doesn't help that you use "additive" in the title. My beef with the term "preadditive" is exactly that: it's too close to "additive."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Well, I don't think many people should have problem at that because we get used to talking about "additive structure" no matter in a preadditive, additive or abelian category.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Let $C$ be a category constructed as follows. Let $G$ be a group and let $BG$ be the one-object category with automorphisms $G$. Then adjoin to $BG$ a zero object. This means that $C$ has two objects, $0$ (the zero object) and another object we'll call $c$. There are zero morphisms $0 \to 0, 0 \to c, c \to 0, c \to c$, and the only other morphisms are the automorphisms $g \in G : c \to c$.

By construction, $C$ has a zero object. Any parallel pair of maps has equalizer either $0$ or $c$, and similarly for the coequalizer. The monomorphisms and epimorphisms are precisely the elements of $G$, which are both kernels and cokernels of $0 : c \to c$. So $C$ is binormal.

$C$ can be made into an $\text{Ab}$-enriched category if and only if there is a division ring $D$ whose group of units is $G$, and there are many obstructions to having this property. For example, if $G$ is finite, then so is $D$. By Wedderburn's little theorem, $D$ is a finite field, and so $G$ must be a finite cyclic group of order $q - 1$ for some prime power $q$. More generally, every finite abelian subgroup of $G$ must be cyclic.